# R markdown knit error with pandoc error 83

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I want to knit but I failed. I spend many time for solve it, but I couldn't. I can't knit even basic Rmd code like...

````
---
title: "Untitled"

date: "2022-09-20"


output: html_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE) 
```
````

error said

```
output file: knit.knit.md

"C:/Users/곽민승/Desktop/Install/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS knit.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output knit.html --lua-filter "C:\Users\곽민승\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\곽민승\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --template "C:\Users\곽민승\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --include-in-header "C:\Users\곽민승\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpolhuTr\rmarkdown-str11e44397877.html" 
Error running filter C:\Users\곽민승\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua:
cannot open C:\Users\곽민승\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua: Invalid argument
**error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83**
```

곽민승 is my name, and r markdown packages are installed,
pandoc verson is 2.18,
saving is UTF-8

I know there are lots of solution in google, but I was in hurry because homework due date is tomorrow. PLEASE help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the result of a bug in pandoc's Lua subsystem before 2.19: filenames were assumed to be UTF-8 encoded instead using the local encoding on Windows. The program gets confused by the Korean characters in the path (your name). Try upgrading pandoc, or, better yet, use [Quarto](https://quarto.org).